# Is it now possible to "pop" in and out of universes, after a certain event happened?

Tags: doctor-who, time-lord

The Tenth Doctor (David Tennant) mentioned that anyone could pop in and out of universes when the Time Lords watched over things, right? And that them being gone meant that cross dimensional travel was "tricky" and dangerous?

So, now

> that they have returned from their pocket dimension, shouldn't it be easier?

Was there an explanation to this already existing in the show? (forgive me for I haven't watched the series in a while).

Answer (score 4):

## No

The quote you reference in the question is as follows:

> **Doctor:**  We're not meant to be here. The Tardis draws it's power from the universe, but it's the wrong universe. It's like diesel in a petrol engine.
>
> **Mickey:** But I've seen it in comics. People go hopping from one alternative world to another. It's easy.
>
> **Doctor:** Not in the real world. It used to be easy. When the Time Lords kept their eye on everything, you could hop between realities, home in time for tea. Then they died, and took it all with them. The walls of reality closed, the worlds were sealed. Everything became that bit less kind.
> <sub>[S02E05 - Rise of the Cybermen (Number 10)](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/28-5.htm)</sub>

Once the Time Lords came back, they were put at the end of the universe.

> **General:** Gallifrey is currently positioned at the extreme end of the time continuum, for its own protection. We're at the end of the universe, give or take a star system.
>
> **Doctor:** I know. I came the long way round.
> <sub>[S09E12 - Hell Bent (Number 12)](http://www.chakoteya.net/DoctorWho/35-12.html)</sub>

The important thing to note is that *when the Time Lords kept their eye on everything* you could hop between realities. However, since the Time Lords are now at the end of the universe, they are not keeping an eye on things, and thus unable to regulate (and enable) hopping between realities.

Comment: One might think that a point where every other event in the universe is in the past would be a singularly good point to keep an eye on everything from.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP - Are you keeping an eye on history? What do you propose to do if this one artist guy starts doing bad stuff?

Comment: I don't follow your logic. How do you make the leap from "now existing at the end of the universe" to "cannot regulate reality-hopping like they used to," especially when we are talking about *Time Lords*? Why would you think that Time Lords that could once keep an eye on everything from their original spacetime position, cannot also do so from the far future?

Comment: @JDoe - As they are at the end of the universe *for their own protection*, it would not be wise of them to start galavanting around Time. Since they are staying away from the rest of the universe, they are not in a position to enable reality-hopping.